# PHP shows page source code in browser

Tags: mysql, php, iis

I have Windows 2008 Server with IIS, PHP, MySQL installed on it and there are several PHP websites working fine.  But when I try to open one of my websites in a browser it shows the source code of page instead of executing the PHP code.

I thought that this is related to the MySQL database connection at first, but when I installed `Vs.Php` for Visual Studio 2010 and tried to open my website, it worked.

I think it may be related with IIS settings.  By the way `test.php` works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with some of my sites on my Debian Squeeze server after I upgraded to a newer version of PHP.

The problem was that the PHP pages that weren't loading were using the PHP short form `<? ?>` and I didn't have `short_open_tag` enabled in my `php.ini` file.

If the `short_open_tag` *isn't* enabled, one must use `<?php` instead.

**Solutions:**

1. Enable the `short_open_tag` option in your `php.ini` file. More on that can be found [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).
2. Use the `<?php` open tag instead of `<?`. If using XML in conjunction with PHP, this is the best solution, as PHP short tags conflict with XML.

Comment: There is a setting in the php.ini file called short_open_tag that deals specifically with this. [read about it here](php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: woow, thanks man, it worked. I've been dealing with this for 2 days. Thanks a lot Marcus.

Comment: No problem. I should´ve written a shorter fix. The short_open_tag is by default disabled in newer versions of PHP. Since some programmers like to make it easy, they make these short open tags alot ;) Nojak filled in what I forgot to mention. Thanks againt Nojak :)